# Send a post request to my mongodb data base

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Hey guys am new to coding and am working on a project where I have a website the client/customer is to make a deposit and when he clicks on submit the form sends a post request to the database where I the admin will approve it and it will reflect on the client/customer dashboard, but because am new to using mongodb and programming as a whole am finding it difficult to figure out how to implement this logic in code I use node.js with express.js and mongodb with mongoose. I hope no one finds this question offensive I just feel like the Udemy course didn't go into details to teach me enough

I know how to set the form to make the request the remaining part of the code to carry out the function I explained above is what am completely blank on

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have express server and then Mongodb with it. When customer post the form, you can create an entry in db and schema of the collection should contain a field as a flag "approved" which will be false by default.

Now when you fetch from collection for the Customer table, fetch with query as { approved: true }, so that unless the approve field is not true it will not include the document.

Now what you can do is create an admin panel, and from there admin can update that field ( approved ) to true.

Only when admin will update the field, then only customer will see that entry on its table.

For this whole process you should know following process:

- Making APIs
- Creating MongoDB document
- Updating MongoDB document
- Fetching MongoDB document